# getting a single databse value into text box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle11g

I would really appreciate if there is any reference to show in how i could transfer value from database into textbox. This my code for combobox, but instead of combobox i would like in textbox

```
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("select subject_name from  subjecti where subject_name = '" + comboBoxSubjectName.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        oda.Fill(dt);
        comboBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.DataSource = dt;
        comboBoxSubjectCodeUpdate.DisplayMember = "subject_name";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
string myquery = "SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable";

using (var command = new OleDbCommand(myquery, connection))
{
  MyTextBox.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Please note if you will be returning multiple values then I suggest you use `ExecuteReader()` as `ExecuteScalar()` only returns a single value.

Comment: thanks i try and see. Mope, i will only return a single value

Comment: If it's single value then you can stick with `ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: o..k.. thanks... i testing it now.. and reading on ExecuteScalar and ExecuteReader

Comment: sir i having problem with this statement ommand.ExecuteScalar() which stating that cannot implictly convert a type object to string

Comment: I've updated it, You need to use `.ToString()` that will return the string

Comment: thanks sir it is working only i must fix my error and find reaosons when i put this comboBoxSubjectCodeRegister.SelectedIndex = -1;
 in combobox the output is an error which is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." but if i remove the statement it display based on what specifies in the combox. So i will try find how can i put comboBoxSubjectCodeRegister.SelectedIndex = -1; without getting an error

Comment: Read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) it will help you with the error

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help. Good luck with your project